# Averaging array values not coming out as expected, gives out of place value instead of correct one

Tags: java, arrays, average

I'm writing a program for a class at school, and when the independents couldn't help, I turn to you...

I encounter my issue when I attempt to find the average - the variables either don't add correctly or they don't divide correctly. For example, an input of [4], [2], [4], [2], will give me 7.0, when it should be 3.0. Similarly, [2], [2], [4], [4], will give 2.0.

As far as I'm aware, the rest of the code functions exactly as it should. I'm including only what should effect it, but I can post the rest if required.

```
public class ArrayFunctions
{
    String elementNumber =
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many elements do you want?");
            int number = Integer.parseInt(elementNumber);

//assigns how many elements are in the array, based on user input

    int[] min_array = new int[number];

    int recalculate = 0;

public void arrayValues()
{


    for (int i = 1; i < (number + 1); i++)
    {
        String elementInfo =
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input value for element " + i);
            int element = Integer.parseInt(elementInfo);

//assigns values for elements, based on user input

        min_array[(i - 1)] = element;
    }

    System.out.println('\u000C'); /*using BlueJ, this clears the console*/

    for (int i = 1; i < (number + 1); i++)
    {
        System.out.println(min_array[(i - 1)]);
    }

//prints the values of the elements in the array
}
```

...

```
public double avg()
{      
    for (int i = 1; i < (min_array.length); i++)
    {
        recalculate = (recalculate + min_array[(i - 1)]);
    }

//should add together the values of all the elements
//this may be where it stops working as intended

    double array_avg = (recalculate / min_array.length);
    return array_avg;

//should divide the sum of all the elements by how many elements there are
//this is the other place where it might stop working.

}
```

Again, I can post more code if required. Sorry about bad/lacking comments and poor structure at times, I need to get this written, because I've a due date for this. :/

Comment: I find it quite strange that you choose to start your loops from 1 instead of 0 and then proceed to substract 1 each time you use the value. Any particular reason?

Comment: Because you're going from index 0 to index array.length - 2, instead of -1. Fix that, and you'll probably be fine.

Comment: Thanks all. I was unaware (pretty new to Java) that I could start at 0. Teacher couldn't help me either.

Comment: Really doesn't sound like the best teacher around!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 1; i < (min_array.length); i++)
{
    recalculate = (recalculate + min_array[(i - 1)]);
}
```

This loop is going between index 0 (1 - 1) and index min_array.length - 2   due to your boolean condition in the for loop, stating that it should go while i is LESS than the array's length, and then also subtracting it by 1 in the code.

A possible solution would be to simply go until it's less than OR equal to the size, or simply start your loop at 0 and stop the (i - 1) stuff in the average calculation.

```
for (int i = 0; i < min_array.length; i++)
{
    recalculate += min_array[i];
}
```

Also, on a side note, you're basically making that same mistake in the GUI stuff as well above; I've corrected it (as well as kept your methodology of using 1-based indexing for asking the user to fill in values, rather than 0-based indexing)

```
for (int i = 0; i < number; i++){
    String elementInfo =
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input value for element " + (i + 1));
        int element = Integer.parseInt(elementInfo);

    min_array[i] = element;
}

System.out.println('\u000C'); /*using BlueJ, this clears the console*/

for (int i = 0; i < number; i++){
    System.out.println(min_array[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're going from index 0 to index array.length - 2, instead of -1. That's the problem. I hope this helps

```
public double avg()
{      
    for (int i = 0; i < (min_array.length); i++)
    {
        recalculate = (recalculate + min_array[i]);
    }

    //should add together the values of all the elements
    //this may be where it stops working as intended

    double array_avg = (recalculate / min_array.length);
    return array_avg;

    //should divide the sum of all the elements by how many elements there are
    //this is the other place where it might stop working.

}
```

Also always start a for loop with `i=0` for counting purposes

Comment: There are many, many cases where you don't start a for loop with i = 0. But in most cases for counting, you definitely do want to.